# How does this sorting code work? How does it find the minimum numbers?

Tags: python, sorting

I found this code on stack overflow answering a topic I was working on (how to sort a list of integers without using sort and sorted built-in functions):

```
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
new_list = []

while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list
    for x in data_list:
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)

print(new_list)
```

It works perfectly well. But when I go through it I get confused on how it works.

`minimum` is set to the first element in the list, `-5`.
When the `for` loop kicks in it starts with the first element of the list. `x` is thereby equal to `-5`, and so `x` is not less than `minimum`. How can the iteration go on, then?

Comment: The if statement doesn't evaluate to True on the first item you're correct, why would that break the for loop though?

Comment: The loop goes through the entire list regardless of what happens with the `if` statement on any particular iteration.

Comment: The first 4 lines of the loop can all be replaced by `minimum = min(data_list)`.

Comment: Recommend [visualize Python](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display).

Comment: yes @John Jugelman you are rigth and I can see how it works now thanks to visualize python. Thank you for that @ jarmod. But is there any further explaination why python behaves this way. Logically it should stop at the first iteration. I would be grateful for anybody who could explain. This would be a fantastic way to learn instead of just replicating what other coders are doing. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some [step-by-step visualization](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=data_list%20%3D%20%5B-5,%20-23,%205,%200,%2023,%20-6,%2023,%2067%5D%0Anew_list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Awhile%20data_list%3A%0A%20%20%20%20minimum%20%3D%20data_list%5B0%5D%20%20%23%20arbitrary%20number%20in%20list%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20data_list%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3C%20minimum%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20minimum%20%3D%20x%0A%20%20%20%20new_list.append%28minimum%29%0A%20%20%20%20data_list.remove%28minimum%29%0A%0Aprint%28new_list%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=43&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) will help you.
I already put your code inside, however, it's not an optimal way to make a sort implementation. You can check the following algorithms: *quicksort*, *merge sort*, *bubble sort*, etc.

Programiz has a general explanation of [different sorting algorithms](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/sorting-algorithm).

Also there you can find [algorithms in general, with their implementation](https://www.techiedelight.com/top-25-algorithms-every-programmer-should-know/) to visualize them in pythontutor step-by-step.

I know it's a lot, but I hope it's gonna help you some how.

Answer (score 1):

The code works by finding the minimum of `data_list`, removing it from `data_list` and appending it to `new_list`. So it stores numbers in `new_list` from least to greatest.

```
data_list = [-5, -23, 5, 0, 23, -6, 23, 67]
new_list = []

while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]  # get default number as a placeholder, minimum does not store minimum yet
    for x in data_list:
        if x < minimum: # if it finds a new minimum
            minimum = x # then minimum is set to that
    #since it checked all values of data_list, now, minimum is definitely the minimum
    new_list.append(minimum) # new_list has the minimum added
    data_list.remove(minimum) # the number is now in the correct position, so it can be discarded.

print(new_list)
```